# Bootstrap toggle nav not rendering @ 768px-992px break

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, toggle, nav

Bootstrap toggle nav not rendering @ 768px-992px break. Please advise.
http://www.marinwaldorf.org/New/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap.css does not display the toggle nav >768px, you can override the bootstrap.css in your local .css to display the toggle nav up to 992px, then this will show the nav up to 992px, then hide the other elements to show the menu as it does <768px.

Something along the lines of..

```
@media (max-width:992px){
    .navbar-header{
        display:block !important;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I put .navbar-header{
 display:block!important;
}
into my min-width:768px;  This did not help.

Comment: Try going into the bootstrap.css and where all the nav-bar css is located within the file, it should be surrounded by a media query of max-width 768px, so try changing this to 992px, which should solve the problem directly from the bootstrap.css.

Comment: I looked at the bootstrap.css and I don't understand how I would do what you suggest AND I also have styles in my custom layout.css that override some of the default. Any more help or clarification would be appreciated.